# Forzar la ejecucion de varios scripts

Tags: html, script, ejecutar, blogger

Hola quisiera saber si hay una forma de ejecutar varios scripts al mismo tiempo, al tocar en cualquier parte de la página

Comment: en un browser no tiene sentido hablar de ejecución de scripts. Se ejecutan funciones. Si un script contiene una IIFE, cargar el script ejecuta su función, pero no es igual a lo que ocurre con un js ejecutado via node

Answer (score 0):

Es de lo mas básico, recomendación, no te saltees pasos.

te paso código, confírmame si es lo que buscas:

HTML

```
<div id="ejecutar_scripts"></div>
```

CSS

```
#ejecutar_scripts {
    width:100%;
}
```

JS

```
var clic = document.getElementById('ejecutar_scripts').addEventListener('click', ()=> {

//acá adentro el codigo que quieras ejecutar//


});
```

Comment: No me sirvió, pero gracias